# В каком порядке читать книги по java?

Tags: java

В каком порядке следует читать следующие книги по java новичку в программировании.

1. Полный справочник по Java. Java SE™ 6 Edition (7-e издание)
2. Хорстман, Корнелл. Java 2 - двух томник
3. Брюс Эккель - Философия Java.
4. Java 2 Ноутон, Шилдт
5. Джошуа Блох - Java. Эффективное программирование

Читал в интернете, что очень хороши книги издательства O'Relly. Нашел следующие книги этого издательства по java: Дэвид Флэнаган - Java. Справочник. 4-е издание и Дэвид Флэнаган - Java в примерах. Справочник. Что можете сказать на счет этих двух книг и стоит ли с них начинать изучать java?

Answer (score 4):

Классика у вас в правильно порядке 2 -> 3 ->6. Хорстман покажет вам Java, Эккель и Блох научит правильно писать на Java. Справочник возможно и не пригодится, ведь есть JavaDoc (хотя у меня был аналогичный по С++ и пользоваться им я любил).

Answer (score 2):

Только Блоха читайте 2 издание и обязательно в оригинале.
К нему бы посоветовал приступить последним, когда уже будет небольшой опыт в Java. Тогда будет легче понимать вещи, которые там описаны. Все-таки это книга не для совсем новичков.

Comment: Эккеля тоже лучше в оригинале

Answer (score 1):

Мое мнение таково:
4 не читаем, ибо старое издание. Читаем сперва 1. Далее можно 3, потом 5 и 2 когда будете хорошо знать язык, ибо она заточена(второй том) на описание классов, библиотек

Answer (score 1):

5-ая книга - лучшая из всех приведенных выше. Но только при наличии начального опыта программирования на Java. Начальный опыт надо получать практически, пользуясь, в основном, JavaDoc и Хорстманом.

Comment: Блоха читать только на английском, во втором издании, иначе смысла не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Всё же рекомендую изучать Java по Oracle's Java Tutorials.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

А если из книг - то начинать с "Хорстман, Корнелл. Java 2".
А лучше совмещать. Доки обязательно нужно читать!)

Answer (score 1):

Насчет O'Relly. Если ты еще совсем новичок, то советую прочитать книгу "Изучаем Java" авторов Кэти Сьерра, Берт Бэйтс.

Answer (score 0):

Если программирование на C++ (хотя даже если и нет), то лучше начните с Хорстмана, а потом Эккель и Блох.