# Литература по Java

Tags: java, книги

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте какую-нибудь хорошую книгу по этому языку (для новичка или для профессионала - не имеет разницы) . Можно также какой-нибудь полезный ресурс (сайт), если знаете. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Двухтомник Java 2. К.Хорстманна, Г.Корнелл. Эти люди знают толк в Java. Если программирование десктопных приложений заинтересует более глубоко, обратите внимание на книгу отечественного автора: И.Портянкина "SWING: Эффективные пользовательские интерфейсы". Это лучшая книга по SWING на русском языке.

Answer (score 3):

Не имеет разницы для новичка или профессионала? Жестко Вы.

Советую вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22658/%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java) взять список. Пожалуй там указаны самые лучшие книги по Java. Философию советую читать в английском варианте, ибо перевод от Питера ее откровенно угробил.

Answer (score 1):

Литературы в интернете много, но думаю что вам следует подумать не только о изучение языка но еще о математической составляющей программирования, стоит зайти [сюда](http://codeforces.com/), различные структуры в программирование [сюда](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/)!! Удачи в изучение!